# Ant : sshexec outputproperty not working as expected

Tags: ant

sshexec outputproperty not working as expected in Ant.

Ant Version : 1.9.4

Command :

```xml
<sshexec host="${Server}"
                username="${User}"
                Password="${Password}"
                trust="true"
                command="${cmd}"
                failonerror="true"
                outputproperty="sshexecOutput" /> 
<echo message="Value of outputproperty ${sshexecOutput}" />`
```

Logs :

```
[sshexec] Connecting to <Server_Name>:22
[sshexec] cmd : <SSHEXEC_COMMAND>
[sshexec] 1
[echo] value of outputproperty 0
```

Can you please help?

Comment: can you add `verbose="true"` parameter to sshexec task and add output to your question

Comment: what are you expecting?

Comment: It should be :
@Rao 
[sshexec] Connecting to <Server_Name>:22
[sshexec] cmd : <SSHEXEC_COMMAND>
[sshexec] 1
[echo] value of outputproperty **1**